# High chart column graph space issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using high charts to plot graphs.I have a combination of area range and column graph.My issue is when i plot a column graph there is a space issue between bar and grid lines.How can i remove this space.Please see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

that is the border width of the column.

You can control it from plotOptions

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},
```

You can set it to "borderWidth: 0" to remove that space. By default it is set to 1

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/xoh93zeu/) is a jsfiddle for the same. feel free to fiddle with that example.